# How to split combined string

Tags: php

I have a string which looks like this:

```
21/04/2014,16:57:28,19,0,2021/04/2014,16:57:48,19,0,20
```

I would like to split it so that I get something like the following:

```
21/04/2014,16:57:28,19,0,20
21/04/2014,16:57:48,19,0,20
```

I have tried using php's substr which I thought was giving results but it duplicated this '21/04/2014,16:57:48,19,0,20' twice.

```
$data3 = array(substr($data1, -27), substr($data1, 27));
```

Even tried a regex with no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "split" ? Store each of them in a different variable or juste print them on a different line ?

Comment: Helper questions: you encountered this situation but what was your original goal? The pieces you are trying to separate look like two different rows from a CSV file. How they ended up being joined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elon Than's answer is the perfect solution if, as he states, the length is constant. However, I just thought I'd add this solution in case (for example) the '19' could also be '3' (or whatever):

```
preg_match_all("/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\,\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{1,2},\d{1},\d{2}/", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Notice the `\d{1,2}` will include any number that is 1 or 2 digits.

Answer (score 8):

If length of parts you want to get is constant you can use `str_split` function with second parameter.

```
$data = str_split($string, 27);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data3 = array(substr($data1, 0, 27), substr($data1, 27));
```